# upgrading ruby how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded to ruby 1.8.7.  i'm running Rails 2.3.5 and rubyGems 1.5.2.

ever since I upgraded, every time I want to start the server, i get:

```
undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0x1022cc1c8> (NameError)
```

[this](http://excid3.com/blog/2011/02/undefined-local-variable-or-method-version_requirements-for-nameerror/) post here advises to downgrade rugyGems to a version below 1.5.0.

downgrading doesn't seem to be the right solution..should I maybe be upgrading Ruby or Rails instead?

Also, if I upgrade to the latest ruby (1.9.2) and rails (3.0)..will my application break?
I have a very large application and can't figure out how to upgrade it without breaking the application..

Comment: If you upgrade to Rails 3 it will definitely break. If you upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2, it will probably break. Have a look at RVM https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Nothing beats trying it out and doing tiny steps here. And bundler, git and rvm definitely are your friends here. Rails 3 runs with 1.8.7 just fine, so if you do not need that new stuff, you ought to be fine for a while.

Comment: Rails 2.3.5 should be easily updated to 2.3.10 or 2.3.11, but the road to 3 is usually at least a little bit painful if its a decent sized app. Try opening config/environment.rb and just changing the RAILS_GEM_VERSION and give that a go, or downgrade rubygems as indicated.

Answer (score 2):

That thing about version_requirements is a bug in rubygems - confirmed by their creators.
I've also participated in the bug report on the rubygems :)

```
gem update --system 1.5.0
```

performs a graceful downgrade until this is fixed.

I ran into this issue with some Rails 2.x applications and once also with 3.0.4 application, but with different error message, again, downgrading rubygems solved it.

Comment: p.s. there are good screencasts on upgrading to rails 3. I would recommend you to check out other rails-3 tagged screencasts on this site. http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1 http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2 http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

Answer (score 1):

You should use RVM so you can have both, `1.8` and `1.9.2` Ruby versions, running and you can be working with `rails 2.3.x` and `rails 3.x` the way that you want

Comment: The steps on installing and configuring `RVM` depends on the platform

Comment: RVM is actually really good at coaching you on what to do next and works on everything I've thrown at it.

Comment: "The steps on installing and configuring RVM depends on the platform" The only thing I've seen change on platforms is the needed dependencies, which RVM will spit out when we do `rvm notes`. Otherwise it's been the same steps on several Linux types and Mac OS.

Comment: @the Tin Man - I've been looking around and you're right, basically the same steps on installing and setting up `rvm` on most of Linux Distros and Max OS, Thanks.

Comment: I've installed it multiple times on Mac OS, Ubuntu 64-bit and 32-bit, Linux Mint, Red Hat, and Centos, and didn't see anything in particular that was different with RVM. What did change was whether the OS preinstalled git and curl, which RVM uses to retrieve Ruby, but those are such common dependencies now days that I install them automatically anyway.